# statically built boringssl depend on dynamic c runtime

Tags: c++, static-linking, crt, boringssl

I managed to build boringssl as dll built with /MT and /NODEFAULTLIB
I added the c runtime library in input -> Additional libraries
The toolset was used is LLVM-vs2014

the surprising thing is that I checked ssl.dll and crypto.dll and the exe files built as tests and they depended on the dynamic crt
I executed :

```
dumpbin.exe /DEPENDENTS ssl.dll
```

the output is contained vcruntime14.dll and other crt dlls

EDIT : to be more clear I added the libraries from here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh.aspx

and I also added to the top of CMakeLists.txt file :

```
 set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE} /MT")
 set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} /MT")
 set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE} /MTd")
 set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} /MTd")
```

and to make sure I saw the proberties of many projects and this flag was set

the problem now : I want to use boringssl in a static executable but the libraries seems to be built with /MD

Comment: well this is boring.  what is the question?  i was looking for a  question mark and couldn't find one.

Comment: _"... I added the c runtime library ..."_ which one? Might you have added the dynamic one by mistake?